# Vim — Automatically Doing a Linefeed When Editing a Markdown (.md) File

Tags: terminal, mojave, vi, macvim

*(MacVim 8.2, Terminal Vim 8.2, MacOS 10.14.6 Mojave)*

Not sure when this started happening.

Whenever I edit a file with a `.md` extension, `Vim` immediately does a linefeed after I type certain lines, as below:

e.g. 1

```
### WR <....linefeed when I press <spacebar>...>
```

e.g.2

```
* hello <...linefeed when I press <spacebar>...>
```

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

I had the setting `filetype plugin on` in my `.vimrc`.

Commenting this out solved my problem. (I need to learn more about vim customization, I guess.)

More info here, at the vi stack exchange:

https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11696/what-does-filetype-plugin-on-really-do